# Lyx: export with tracking changes to pdf

Tags: lyx, pdf, trackchanges

I want to export from Lyx a document as a PDF file. Since my person I am sending the file to does not have Lyx I would like to send him the PDF file containing the changes I made since the last version of the document.

I know that *pdflatex* does not preserve the tracking changes as this is documented almost everywhere, however, the same sources say that using  the  *ps2pd*f method or the *Dvipdfm* method this information is preserved.

I tried both of them, but the PDF result is still clean without the tracking changes. It appears that I need to do at least one more thing to accomplish what I want.   Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK. I dug a little more through the Lyx's menus and I found the answer.

The solution is to go the menu: Document-> Change Tracking -> Show changes in Output.

Also, worth to be mentioned is that it appears that this works for all 3 PDF export methods including pdflatex.

I am wondering then if this [wiki](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/PDF#ps2pdf) document is wrong or obsolete?

Comment: Glad you found it :-) Please also accept your answer (click the tick so it becomes green), as it, well, answers the question.

Comment: Sure, I'll tick that but I can do it only after 2 days.

Comment: @Bogdan If you think the wiki is wrong, consider sending an email to lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org . If you're confident the wiki is wrong, please feel free to just directly edit it.